# Alternative of rank function in mysql 5.7 to find out latest rescord grouped by cr-id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, window-functions

I have a table something like this:

```
cr-id  prod-name  timestamp 

p1     prod-1     2020-10-06 01:00:00.0
p1     prod-2     2020-10-06 02:00:00.0
p1.    prod-1     2020-07-03 08:32:00.0
p2.    prod-2     2020-06-01 07:39:00.0
p2.    prod-1     2020-04-05 03:32:00.0
p3.    prod-2     2020-03-02 02:23:00.0
p3.    prod-2     2020-07-04 02:23:00.0
```

I want to use a new column rank for the latest date grouped by cr-id. So my output result should look like this:

```
 cr-id  prod-name  timestamp              rank

p1     prod-1     2020-10-06 01:00:00.0    2
p1     prod-2     2020-10-06 02:00:00.0    1
p1.    prod-1     2020-07-03 08:32:00.0    3
p2.    prod-2     2020-06-01 07:39:00.0    1
p2.    prod-1     2020-04-05 03:32:00.0    2
p3.    prod-2     2020-03-02 02:23:00.0    2
p3.    prod-2     2020-07-04 02:23:00.0    1
```

I am using mysql-5.7 so RANK function will not work here. Can you please help me to achieve this in an efficient manner?

Comment: do you want a new column or do you want rank returned from a query?

Comment: I want a new column

Comment: why does the `p1.`  row have rank 3, not rank 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding a rank column, do:

```
set @last='';
set @rank=NULL;
update yourtable
    set rank=if(
        @last=(@last:=cr_id),
        (@rank:=@rank+1),
        (@rank:=1)
    )
order by cr_id,`timestamp`;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select 1 + count(*) 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.cr_id = t.cr_id and t1.timestamp > t.timestamp
    ) rn
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
SELECT t1.`cr-id`, t1.`prod-name`, t1.`timestamp`, COUNT(*) `rank`
FROM src_table t1
JOIN src_table t2 ON t1.`cr-id` = t2.`cr-id`
                 AND t1.`timestamp` >= t2.`timestamp`
GROUP BY t1.`cr-id`, t1.`prod-name`, t1.`timestamp`
```