SQL, return user position based on specific ORDER BY using MySQL 5.7
I have tables
users: (id, name)
scores: (id, user_id, value, created_at)
How can I calculate rank of user by sum of value, but if sum for some users the same upper should be user with highies last date creted_at scores row
Important: use MySQL 5.7 syntax, so I can't use RANK function
I have SQL:
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS user_rank,
        SUM(scores.value) as total_value,
        ( SELECT MAX(created_at) 
             FROM scores 
             WHERE user_id = scores.user_id
        ) as latest_created_at
    FROM
        scores AS main
    GROUP BY
        scores.user_id
    HAVING
        total_value <= (SELECT SUM(scores2.value) FROM scores AS scores2)

If I try to use ORDER BY latest_created_at it doesn't work, any ideas please?
I attached https://dbfiddle.uk/HqpWVADu
SO,
user_id = 3 rank is 2 he has the same value as user 2 but he reach this value first
user_id = 1 rank is 1 because he has 4 score values
user_id = 2 rank is 3
For now it shows wrong positions :(

Please add some sample data and expected output @StanislauKaraliou

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3

If you want alternative of rank() function for MySQL 5.7 then this may be possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64357670/alternative-of-rank-function-in-mysql-5-7-to-find-out-latest-rescord-grouped-by

I tried to reach you issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/97MZq2W2. Please mention what you want correctly...  @StanislauKaraliou

Never say "doesn't work". Show exactly what you tried and explain what does happen

I added dbfiddle and explanation
